# cast de char sobre int introducido por consola (std::cin)

Tags: c++, cast, char, int

El problema reza: Haz un bucle `while` que lea dos `int` y los imprima por consola. El programa finaliza cuando uno de los datos termina en *q*.

Yo pensaba realizar el ejercicio con un `while` similar al primero y he visto que para que haga aproximadamente lo que se pide he tenido que hacer el segundo.

¿Cómo se haría correctamente este programa?

Os dejo mis intentos. El primero comprendo que al pulsar una *q* no es un `int`, se vuelva todo loco. Está muy mal hecho pero lo dejo para que se intuya por donde lo querría hacer, si es posible algo similar. El segundo funciona, sin más, siempre y cuando no le busques las cosquillas.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
     int i1,i2;
     char c1,c2,c;

     while(c1!='q' || c2!='q'){
         std::cin>>i1>>i2;
         std::cout<<i1<<" - "<<i2<<'\n';
         c1 = (char)i1;
         c2 = (char)i2;
     }

     while(std::cin>>i1>>i2){
         std::cout<<i1<<" - "<<i2<<'\n';
         c = _getch();
         if (c == 'q') break;
     }

     return 0;
}
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sobre el primer intento, no puedes verificar que un número sea distinto a un carácter ya que un número no puede almacenar caracteres.

Lo que sí está haciendo es verificar que el valor numérico correspondiente al carácter sea diferente al número leído. O sea, en ASCII a la q le corresponde el 113.

Esto:

```
while(c1!='q' || c2!='q')
```

Es equivalente a esto:

```
while(c1!=113 || c2!=113)
```

---

El segundo intento se acerca más. Porque `cin` tiene una [conversión implícita a `bool`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) que evalúa `true` siempre que no haya ocurrido ningún error.

El caso es que cuando le pides al programa que lea un número pero se encuentra con otra cosa, se activa el [`failbit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate). [Más información](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt).

Este `failbit` está contemplado en la conversión a `bool` mencionada. Puedes verlo en la tabla del primer link.

Por lo tanto, el ciclo se detiene solo. No necesitas nada más que esto:

```
while(cin >> i1 >> i2){
    cout << i1 << " - " << i2 << '\n'; 
}
```

Si quisieras leer otro dato, deberías llamar a la función [`clear`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) para restablecer el `failbit` sino, seguirá activo. Así:

```
cin.clear();
```

El mejor lugar para hacerlo en tu código sería justo después del ciclo.

---

A medida que leas más información se volverá engorroso leer el código.

Por lo tanto, podrías escribir el código de la siguiente manera:

```
// Lectura
cin >> i1 >> i2;
...

while(cin){
    cout << i1 << " - " << i2 << '\n';
    ...

    // Nuevamente lees las variables
    cin >> i1 >> i2;
    ...
}
```

O si prefieres evitar escribir dos veces lo mismo:

```
while(true){
    // Lectura
    cin >> i1 >> i2;
    ...

    if (!cin) break;

    cout << i1 << " - " << i2 << '\n';
    ...
}
```

---

Verificar si hay un caracter en especial en este caso aumenta un poco la dificultad. Se me ocurre que puedes verificar si el primer caracter no numérico es una `'q'`.

Para eso primero verificas el estado de `cin` para no realizar la verificación a menos que sea necesario. Cuando sí lo es procedes a restablecer el estado de `cin`. Si no lo hicieras las lecturas fallarían por más que la entrada sea correcta sumado a efectos secundarios.

Luego lees cada caracter con `cin.get()` hasta llegar a uno no numérico (y por conveniencia omites los espacios también).

Finalmente verificas si este caracter es `'q'` o no. Para evitar un posible ciclo infinito por llegar al final del stream también verifica si `chr == EOF`.

```
bool checkQ(){
    if (cin) return false;
    cin.clear();

    int chr;
    do {
        chr = cin.get();
    } while (chr == ' ' || (chr > '0' && chr < '9'));

    return chr == 'q' || chr == EOF;
}
```

Entonces la función main ahora se vería así:

```
int main() {
    int i1, i2;

    while(true){
        // Lectura
        cin >> i1;
        if (checkQ()) break;

        cin >> i2;
        if (checkQ()) break;

        cout << i1 << " - " << i2 << '\n';
    
     }
}
```

Puedes probarlo [aquí](https://tio.run/##jVDLbsIwELzvV4xaCSdSKSV9QkJu7alS1XsvwRiwCA44jnoofHu6dkJpb3VkRzu7MzsaudsNV1K27aU2smwWCpmuamdVsc3pjDGizSonamr@o3aL6VRqk/6pq8alRPOqKiHXSm7eo/iLwEcvEfF0DKtcYw2WRVmrNLQYvpalKmwUMzcMG8d027UXFTqJMLu2mAXGSjk/78EjPte6VLzAd2cQ/B0OXZlD3AgMBoGZQUxEfNrSOzmR9oHUV89vLykdibyTbaFNFPcmPKDHV9BJrxJWR842Kj7bHI3wqiTLF2fn2iDPmZv@QCGTPqUYcw5804v@JiT/JnD4yDJe4d8LDPn6MvGv@DCiE@oio2PbjpFQgTnd4o4k7ukBj/S0x@Qb).

Comment: Buenas @Mateo, el caso que me ofreces sale del `while` cuando pulsas una tecla cualquiera, que no sea número.
Y esto es lo que estoy entendiendo, y que sospechaba, siempre que pulsas una tecla que no sea número en un `std::cin` donde la variable que se lee es `int`.
Además tiene todo el sentido puesto que un `char` no es un dígito.

Comment: @Caba se me había olvidado. Ya cargué una posible solución.

Comment: Hola @Mateo, esta último programa aborda mejor una posible solución. A mí me basta. Saludos!!