# Capturar la actividad de la tecla 'Intro' en C++ con cin.peek()

Tags: c++

### Exposición

A partir de aquí: [cast de char sobre int introducido por consola (std::cin)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/567849/cast-de-char-sobre-int-introducido-por-consola-stdcin/567872?noredirect=1#comment1004264_567872) , al final decidí realizar el ejercicio, nada importante, si no fuese porque para capturar un carácter `'\n'` tuve que recurrir a la siguiente condición:

```
std::cin.peek() == '\n'
```

El `peek()` en flujos de entrada, como es el caso del `std::cin`, lo único que realiza es recuperar el siguiente carácter de ese flujo sin usarlo. En este caso obtenemos un valor de `true` cuando el siguiente carácter del flujo es `'\n'`.
Encontrar documentación en español es complejo, por eso lo comento. En mi caso, necesitaba conocer cuando pulsaba la tecla 'Intro' del teclado y fue por ahí por donde pude hacerlo.

### Pregunta

¿Existe alguna solución más simple que ésta para capturar cuando se pulsa 'Intro'?

### Código Completo

[Aquí se puede ver el código](https://tio.run/##jVRNb9swDL3rVzAZ0NidU9ReFrSx3SFre9htwLABA3pRHTUh6kiZZHfohvz2TLJlW84HOl8iUeQj@fiYbLMZL7Nst3uHPMvLBYMEhSoko@sbQpAXgGGAUYCBwiUXMXkUIgemvvDiOxeBPs15wSQKOf8qcc3kHS6x0A@K5igDWNE/nzXYc0yyFZWQs6woJY0JeRG4AOSYIZU/qET6mDPl@X8J6K/BhxQKWbLYGo@m6vk06bTxiebKWqta9kymG20K6yuG@nxpz1F3tvXWhm1NiLX9vBX8hUmFgt@xW93cvK6n6UEVi9ksQ36xZIVnY3yb4Qm8FjmF0a@R39bY9bLvNR7B2dkpFvy2o3HYhZ90Ps2lw5FTwE06uqzS23uSjq510ZLpC29ZGqcwubLD0ijNc1hzZ5VzbxI3JJkULVEbxp49v@r1gY@sxxtUms@m6ZjbHpRgu7ITVFiU1LbsGQMv1wFUYrdZbZi2w7muH94DVtGVaqkWp@d6t3L9VAupjx9qaB9mta76T5F56oA3gjP5zczR5adBdwjRWc5TsBvZstSX9N4eOXP932VyaDR1DI4VEh0pxFlCF8ySv6bIPZ/UGL9XmDNvUIlfw3a4B38MMdmTgyiLJBlWZTNYCGWGxaT@ZaYxoWYPfOgE2UxNbW6yhuhBK06nw9ZBd/Pm5seHYRoXB2l46VvZ7Plse7eKa1cFnfP2eP/3OWyq@dm29WBnMIQkMRrR7wG8alRQbFnyheg5GZ/I@FxUTLXor6pga2@4oaViQ//wIctVY966y2K2fLcLow8TMp1MJ4SMw@gjmV5f/QM), por si alguien no tiene clara esta solución y quiere ver cómo lo implementé yo.

Por cierto, el problema rezaba: Haz un bucle `while` que lea dos `int` y los imprima por consola. El programa finaliza cuando uno de los datos termina en q.

En fin, disculpad por el programa chapuza, el asunto es que si no le buscas las cosquillas, funciona. ;)

Comment: ¿Quieres detectar cuando se presiona una tecla o solo cuando aparezca en la entrada del programa?

Comment: Hola @Mateo , si puedieras explicarme ambas cosas, sería de agradecer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Determinar si una tecla está siendo presionada es algo que depende del sistema operativo.

En Windows puedes usar [`GetAsyncKeyState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate):

```
// El bit más significativo es 1 si está presionado y 0 si no
if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN) & 0x8000)
{
    // Enter presionado
}
```

También hay otras funciones que pueden o no estar disponibles en tu compilador.  Por ejemplo [`_kbhit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/kbhit) para saber si una tecla fue presionada y [`_getch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getch-getwch) para saber cuál.

En mi Windows el caracter correspondiente a enter es `'\r'`:

```
if (_kbhit() && _getch() == '\r') {
    // Enter presionado
}
```

---

##### Edición

Por lo que veo quieres hacer algo que reemplace a `system("pause")`.

`_kbhit` comprueba si una tecla se presionó en el momento en que la función se ejecuta. No se queda esperando hasta que presiones una tecla.

En cambio, `_getch` sí. Entonces lo más cercano que puedes hacer es lo siguiente:

```
cout << "Presiona una tecla para continuar...";
// El programa esperará a que cualquier tecla sea presionada
_getch();
cout << '\n';
```

O si quieres una solución portable, podrías usar `cin.get` con el mismo propósito ya que provocará que la consola espere hasta que el usuario de alguna entrada.

```
cout << "Presiona una tecla para continuar...";
// El programa esperará a que cualquier tecla sea presionada
cin.get();
```

Eso sí, `get` solo obtendrá el primer caracter. Si el usuario escribe más caracteres tendrás información extra.

Puedes quitarla mediante `cin.ignore()`, por ejemplo `cin.ignore(1000000, '\n')`. O también con `cin.get`:

```
int c = -1;
while (c != '\n')
    c = cin.get();
```

Comment: No me funcionan la segunda condición, @Mateo. Será por el compilador? No me da error de compilación y la librería la tengo. Estoy trabajando con el code::blocks y minGW para C++17.

Comment: @Caba Puedes ser más descriptivo? ¿Qué no te funciona, o qué es lo que esperas que pase y no pasa?

Comment: Eso siempre @Mateo. Sencillamente hice un programa que escribiera 'Hola mundo' al pulsar la tecla 'Intro'. Así que agarré los dos ìf` y los probé poniendo con anterioridad `system("pause")`. El del  `GetAsyncKeyState` escribe el 'Hola mundo', pero el segundo no. No sé si fue por el compilador, si fue porque hay algo que ignoro o que no he entendido, etc...

Comment: Buenas @Mateo, en vez del `system("pause")`, metí los `if` dentro de un bucle infinito, y ahí si, ya veo como funcionan los dos. Por cierto, el del `GetAsyncKeyState` es muy sensible. Parece que va por el tiempo que pulsas "Enter", o al menos eso me pareció. Gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: Acabo de leer tu Edición @Mateo, y más información interesante, de verdad, gracias por tu tiempo. Lo que hice se parece más al bucle infinito y poder darle una condición de salida, que al `system("pause")`.